# insert ...select ... count ... on duplicate key update error

Tags: insert-update

I created a table to hold counts of work orders by asset tag.  I have 2 fields, asset_tag (which is unique) and the wo_count.  I am trying to write a query that will insert/update the counts in the table.  Through research on `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, I have come up with this, but am getting unknown column errors.

```
INSERT INTO mod_workorder_counts (asset_tag, wo_count) 
    (SELECT t.asset_tag, count(*) AS cnt 
        FROM mod_workorder_data t
        WHERE t.asset_tag IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY t.asset_tag)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mod_workorder_counts.wo_count = t.cnt
```

When I run this I get `#1054 - Unknown column 't.cnt' in 'field list'`.  I am not sure how to use the count values in the update.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Once you reference it as "cnt", you no longer need the "t." portion.  You should reference it as just "cnt".