# MySQL and PHP for attendance

Tags: php, mysql

I know that there are quite a few different topics out there but I don't believe they are exactly what I'm looking for.

I need to make a database using MySQL for a club I'm in. I want to create a webpage that the Secretary can log into and take attendance for the meeting. First off I need to know what exactly I would need for creating the table.

I was thinking something like

```
CREATE TABLE 'Members'('memberName' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    '11/1/11' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    'totalAttendance' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
     PRIMARY KEY('memberName'), UNIQUE INDEX 'memberName'_UNIQUE('memberName' ASC));
```

and just keep adding columns for the date using `ALTER TABLE 'Members' ADD '11/8/11' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;`

I was going to use PHP to create the column and change the default 0 to a 1 if they attended (not exactly sure how I was going to do that but I was thinking some check boxes and if they are checked edit that column for that name?) So something like `mysql_query("UPDATE 'Member' SET 'meetingDate'='1' WHERE memberName='nameOfMember'") 
or die(mysql_error());` I believe.

What I really need is a way to count across each column to count the total number of times each member has attended and then placing that into the totalAttendance column.

Can someone help me out with that? I'm thinking it is a really easy statement I'm just not asking Google the correct question. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: [Fundamentals of Relational Database Design](http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx)

Comment: Gaaah... dates as field names? Gag me with a pitchfork!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you set up something like this:

```
id    |  MeetingDate |    MemberName    |    Present
 1    |  2011-11-01  |    John Doe      |       1
 2    |  2011-11-01  |    John Smith    |       0
 3    |  2011-11-01  |    John Jackson  |       1
 4    |  2011-11-02  |    John Doe      |       0
 5    |  2011-11-02  |    John Smith    |       1
 6    |  2011-11-02  |    John Jackson  |       1
 7    |  2011-11-03  |    John Doe      |       1
 8    |  2011-11-03  |    John Smith    |       1
 9    |  2011-11-03  |    John Jackson  |       1
```

So you'd have a row for each member for each meeting whether they attended or not. My guess is you're not going to have millions and millions of rows with this system, so don't worry about performance.

You can get the total attendance for a member with something like:

```
SELECT SUM(Present) as total FROM attendance WHERE MemberName = 'John Doe';
// returns -> 2
```

You can get the total attendance for a meeting with something like:

```
SELECT SUM(Present) as total FROM attendance WHERE MeetingDate = 2011-11-01;
// returns -> 2
```

You can get all of the members that missed a specific meeting with something like:

```
SELECT MemberName FROM attendance WHERE Present = 0 AND MeetingDate = 2011-11-01;
// returns -> John Smith
```

Comment: +1 Storing a record (with Present = 0) for people who *missed* a meeting might not be necessary, but it is nice. It avoids confusion between missing a meeting and not being in the group at the time of the meeting.

Comment: I think I'm going to try this method because it does what I wanted it to do pretty easily. Thank you very much. If it works I'll set it as the accepted answer but if it doesn't I'll just keep posting.

Comment: Okay so I hit one snag of the Primary Key. If I have it set as the ID then I can't have two occurrences of the same person if they have two different meetings.

Comment: not sure what you mean... the id is unique for **each** person at **each** meeting. You would basically duplicate each person for each meeting in the db. I'll update my answer with more rows in the table.  (although I would pull the members out to a separate table to normalize a bit -- that wouldn't be necessary in this small of an application)

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to post that. I figured that part out. What I need to know now is how to query all the unique names and output them into some html form. I want to make a list of names with a checkboxes next to them. And then a submit button at the end. Once the user presses submit it should create a row of every one of the names including whether they were present or not. Understand?

Comment: @eric, Ooh... This seems to have taken on a different flavor since I voted for it. It's completely [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (bad). You should have a separate table for Members (MemberId, Name, ...) and another for Meetings (MeetingId, Date, ...). The table that records attendance would be MemberMeeting (MemberId, MeetingId, Present). The PK would be both MemberID and MeetingID. To get all members, you just query the Members table!

Comment: @grossvogel - from a purist standpoint, I agree with you. If this application would grow to anything more than an attendance record, then you should definitely normalize the database (I mentioned that above).

Comment: @grossvogel - We're not talking millions and millions of records here, so duplicating members in the db is not going to hurt performance of the system. I agree it's not the "correct" solution according to db admins out there, but the system will get the job done without causing any additional problems.

Comment: @swatkins: IMO, normalization is mostly about a single point of truth and conceptual correctness, not optimizing storage. If a member's name changes, you have to update all of their attendance records. Two meetings cannot happen on the same day, and two members cannot have the same name. If you want to add PhoneNumber for your members or a Topic for your meetings, you have to add it to every attendance record. If you want to create checkboxes to take attendance, the only members available are the ones who have ALREADY attended a meeting. So it's impossible to attend your first meeting!

Answer (score 4):

Please **Please** *Please* do not do this.

Make every date a new row.
Make a date column.

So your table would look something like this:

```
  ID   |    Date      | Attendance |  
   1   |  2011-11-01  |      5     |
   2   |  2011-11-02  |      12    |
   3   |  2011-11-03  |      3     |
```

Then you can have a table of members.

Then you can have a join table of member to meeting. -- 
    Then when you have this you do not even need an `Attendance` column in the Meeting table because you can just count how many members are at each meeting with a simple query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.date, count(*) as `attendance`
FROM meeting m
LEFT JOIN meeting_to_member mm ON mm.meetingid = m.id
LEFT JOIN member mem ON mem.id = mm.memberid 
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using INSERT into... SELECT COUNT...

Look at this guys code:
[insert ...select ... count ... on duplicate key update error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687971/insert-select-count-on-duplicate-key-update-error)

You can cut out a lot of his query but it should help.